# How to mark evey next 100 meter travelled in map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am trying to get the GPS location co-ordinates(lat and lon vals) for every 100metrs.

For example, I am at particular location A and tried to fetch my current location using 
location listener and shown in the map with marker, after that I have travelled 100metres and reached location B and again i tried to fetch location and shown in map with marker.

Good thing :-

i am getting but obvious new lat and lon cordinates for every  next 100 meters.

Annoying Thing:-

Marker for location A and for location B getting overlapped always, so one cannot make out any sort of difference in between those two locations by dirrectly looking into map :(. How can I overcome this issue. Can you please guide me.?

Comment: Is your problem that the distance between the two markers is too small? Have to tried to zoom in? Maybe make the markers smaller?

Comment: yeah .. i tried zooming it...they looks like overlapped

Comment: I am using satellite view
is there any other alternate to get location more accurately.Is there any 3rd party api available for to get the lat and long vals for better accuracy

Comment: Have you checked in debugging that the coordinates of the markers are actually different? I can imagine there might be a rounding error somewhere.

Comment: Log.i does this work for me..cordiantes were different

Comment: Try some different things then, like manually setting long and lat every 5 seconds or something, and make the difference big to see if that works. The reason you might want to debug is to see that the coordinates are correct even in the Google Maps code.